# (Ruby on Rails) - NoMethodError in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm doing the four hour course on Ruby on Rails on YouTube from FreeCodeCamp and am struggling around 1:57:00 in the video. During this part of the course we added the Devise gem and are adding a Sign Up, Sign Out, and Edit Profile links to our nav bar. I double checked my code and re-watched this part of the video several times now, but when I go to 'sign up' on the site via local host this error shows in the browser:

```
NoMethodError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create

     if options.empty?
                  recipient.public_send(method, *args)
                else
                  recipient.public_send(method, *args, options)
                end
```

And this message pops up on the terminal:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `user_url' for #<Devise::RegistrationsController:0x0000000000c9e0>

              recipient.public_send(method, *args)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^):
```

Following this is a ton of actionpack, activesupport, responders, etc lines. Just looking to see if anyone can help me and explain exactly what's wrong so I can fix it.

Comment: What version of rails?  Did you run `rails generate devise:install`? What MODEL did you use when you ran `rails generate devise MODEL`?

Comment: @dbugger I have Rails 7.0.1 installed. Yes, I did do rails generate devise:install. I followed these instructions along with the course: 

https://github.com/heartcombo/devise#starting-with-rails

Answer (score 2):

modify below files

**app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { data: { turbo: false} } ) do |f| %>
```

**app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name), html: { data: { turbo: false} } ) do |f| %>
```

ref: [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues/5358#issuecomment-798796788)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're still having this issue. Like zaheed pointed out above, it seems like the error is likely coming from `views/home/_header.html.erb`, specifically the `new_user_session_path` part of the list form block mentioned in the video.